# adding electrical GFCI plug

Tags: electrical-distribution

can a GFCI outlet be added to the end of a circuit? if so do you need a 3 core wire? we have tried to install with 2 core wire but it dosent seem to work

Comment: When you say "*3 core wire*". Do you mean three wires plus a ground (so four total wires), or two wires plus a ground (three wires total)?  Are you trying to GFCI protect other devices on the circuit, or just the GFCI receptacle?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the ground wire or 3rd wire is desirable & preferred. If you can't ground the circuit or can't afford an Electrician to do so or to re-wire the circuit, then it's fine to use. A GFCI will work anywhere & still provides protection without the ground wire. They're specifically approved for ungrounded old homes, but it won't pass a plug-in tester's scrutiny.

[**Here's a good article on the subject for your understanding.**](http://ecmweb.com/content/replacing-2-wire-ungrounded-receptacles)

Comment: it's a good idea to label the outlet "no equipment ground" if there isn't a true ground connection.

Comment: A 3-light plug-in tester deliberately induces a ground fault (to light the hot-ground indicator) so you will not be able to test a GFCI with it.